# Spring Boot application reads same messages from Kafka whenever started

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

I have Zookeeper and Apache Kafka servers running on my Windows computer. The problem is with a Spring Boot application: it reads the same messages from Kafka whenever I start it. It means the offset is not being saved. How do I fix it?

Versions are: `kafka_2.12-2.4.0`, `Spring Boot 2.5.0`.

In Kafka listener bean, I have

```
factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
```

Consumer config values printed on console when Spring Boot starts are:

2021-06-10 18:21:11.008  INFO 7036 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig    : ConsumerConfig values:

```
        allow.auto.create.topics = true
        auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
        auto.offset.reset = latest
        bootstrap.servers = [http://localhost:9092]
        check.crcs = true
        client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
        client.id = consumer-group_id1-1
        client.rack =
        connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
        default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
        enable.auto.commit = false
        exclude.internal.topics = true
        fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
        fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
        fetch.min.bytes = 1
        group.id = group_id1
        group.instance.id = null
        heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
        interceptor.classes = []
        internal.leave.group.on.close = true
        internal.throw.on.fetch.stable.offset.unsupported = false
        isolation.level = read_uncommitted
        key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
        max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
        max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
        max.poll.records = 500
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
        receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
        reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        request.timeout.ms = 30000
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.jaas.config = null
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.login.class = null
        sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
        sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
        sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
        security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        security.providers = null
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        session.timeout.ms = 10000
        socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 127000
        socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
        ssl.engine.factory.class = null
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
        ssl.keystore.key = null
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.certificates = null
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

UPDATE 11-Jun-2021
Using @nipuna's suggestion, in my Kafka consumer config, I set
`props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);`

However, this was not compatible with ack mode manual_immediate, so I deleted the following line to use the default ack mode (batch, I think).

`factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);`

Comment: Please share your Consumer code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is here `enable.auto.commit = false`. If you are not manually committing offset after consuming messages, You should configure this to `true`

If this is set to false, after consuming messages from Kafka, there is no feedback to Kafka whether you read or not. Then after you restart your consumer it will send messages from the start. If you enable this, your consumer make sure it will automatically send your last read offset to Kafka. Then Kafka saved that offset in __consumer_offsets topic with your consumer `group_id`, `topic` you consumed and `partition`.

Then after you restart the consumer, Kafka read your last position from `__consumer_offsets` topic and send from there.